# First two records of each group based on rank

Tags: sql, teradata

I've created a part of the query that returns me the data like in the picture below:
Now, I am trying to select First 2 records (1 and 2) of each group (sap_id, wr_nbr) where "rn" has more than 1.

[image]

So, my final table should look like:

[image]

I've tried with TOP 2 WITH TIES but it returns me only two records of the whole table.
Any idea how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not filter on RN? `RN <= 2`?

Comment: @EdwardRadcliffe I tried, but it will filter me the sap_id = 99902 and wr_nbr = 9988705156 as well 
 as it has rn = 1

Comment: Based on the additional info you posted as "answer", this should be tagged `sql-server` and not `teradata`. Add `,MAX(rn) OVER (PARTITION BY sap_id,wr_nbr) AS max_rn` to your inner query and filter `WHERE  max_rn >= 2 AND rn <=2` in the outer query.

Comment: How is `rn`calculated, is it based on`row_number` or `rank`?

Comment: @dnoeth Yes, it is calculated based on the row_number.

Comment: @Fred I created this example in Microsoft SQL, but the original query is associated with teradata. I will try your solution later and will let you know the result. Is there a way to avoid inner join?

Comment: Ok, can you show the row_number calculation?

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.sap_id, d.wr_nbr ORDER BY d.sap_id, d.wr_nbr, d.start_date ASC) AS rn

Comment: After that, I created a new one query:
' SELECT a.[sap_id]
,a.[wr_nbr]
,a.[start_date]
,a.[end_date]
,a.[vs_ind]
,a.[rn]
FROM
(SELECT [sap_id]
  ,[ts_nbr]
  ,[wr_nbr]
  ,[check_line]
  ,[check_nbr]
  ,[start_date]
  ,[end_date]
  ,[vs_ind]
  ,[rn]
  ,[rank_ind]
   FROM [dbo].[first_two]) a
WHERE a.rn <=2 '

Comment: What INNER JOIN? You can use `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY d.sap_id, d.wr_nbr)` in the same query as the `ROW_NUMBER` to figure out if there are at least 2 rows in a group.  In SQL Server you need to have those OLAP functions in a subquery and filter with a `WHERE` clause in the outer query; in Teradata you can use `QUALIFY` clause in the same query as the OLAP function and avoid nesting.

Comment: Can you update your OP with the full query you're trying to use? Looking at your sample data with the `RN` column, I'm unsure why `<=` doesn't give you the desired output after reading the comments.

Comment: @Fred - ok, I used `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY d.sap_id, d.wr_nbr)` to figure out if there are at least 2 rows, but after that how to filter first two rows only?

Comment: it seems this solution works fine:
`SELECT b.*
FROM
(SELECT a.[sap_id]
,a.[wr_nbr]
,a.[start_date]
,a.[end_date]
,a.[vs_ind]
,a.[rn]
,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.sap_id, a.wr_nbr) as count_rows
FROM
(SELECT [sap_id]
      ,[ts_nbr]
      ,[wr_nbr]
      ,[check_line]
      ,[check_nbr]
      ,[start_date]
      ,[end_date]
      ,[vs_ind]
      ,[rn]
      ,[rank_ind]
  FROM [dbo].[first_two]) a) b
 WHERE b.count_rows > 1
 and b.rn <= 2`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.*
FROM
(SELECT a.[sap_id]
,a.[wr_nbr]
,a.[start_date]
,a.[end_date]
,a.[vs_ind]
,a.[rn]
,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.sap_id, a.wr_nbr) as count_rows
FROM
(SELECT [sap_id]
  ,[ts_nbr]
  ,[wr_nbr]
  ,[check_line]
  ,[check_nbr]
  ,[start_date]
  ,[end_date]
  ,[vs_ind]
  ,[rn]
  ,[rank_ind]
   FROM [dbo].[first_two]) a) b
WHERE b.count_rows > 1
AND b.rn <= 2
```

Final table looks like:

[image]